# Как запретить ввод url адреса в строку браузера Asp.Net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог вводить в адресную строку /Admin/Index который переводит на админ панель

Answer (score 0):

Никак. ASP.NET MVC - это серверный фреймворк. Он никак не может запретить пользователю вводить что-то в строку браузера.

Если хотите закрыть доступ к админке - делайте это на стороне сервера, через стандарные механизмы аутентификации / авторизация. Создайте новое MVC приложение из шаблона, укажите в визарде "Individual user accounts" и возьмите результат за основу.